# Cant override the color with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make the color of the number green if its  more than zero to make it green and want to be red when its below zero but i cant do it i dont get why can anyone explain

```
const button1 = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
const button2 = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
const main = document.querySelector('.main-container')
const count = document.getElementById('counter')

let counter = 0 



main.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('nextBtn')){
    
    counter++
    
  
html=`
<h1 class="text-uppercase">counter</h1>
<h1 id="counter"class =count">${counter}</h1>
<div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
<button class="btn counterBtn prevBtn text-uppercase m-2">lower count</button>
<button class="btn counterBtn nextBtn text-uppercase m-2">add count</button>
`
main.innerHTML = html

  }else if(e.target.classList.contains('prevBtn')){
    counter--
    
    html=`
<h1 class="text-uppercase">counter</h1>
<h1 id="counter">${counter}</h1>
<div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
<button class="btn counterBtn prevBtn text-uppercase m-2">lower count</button>
<button class="btn counterBtn nextBtn text-uppercase m-2">add count</button>
`
main.innerHTML = html
  }
})

if(counter > 0){
  count.style.color = 'green'
} else if(counter < 0) {
  count.style.color = 'red'
}
```

Comment: You're trying to fetch the element by ID before it's been added to the page content.

Comment: also you have to update the style in the event

Comment: i  did it in listener i tried many ways but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in your code is not correct.
You must get an element **after** it is added to DOM.

Try the snippet.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main-container')

let counter = 0 

main.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('nextBtn')){
    counter++
    html=`
    <h1 class="text-uppercase">counter</h1>
    <h1 id="counter"class =count">${counter}</h1>
    <div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
    <button class="btn counterBtn prevBtn text-uppercase m-2">lower count</button>
    <button class="btn counterBtn nextBtn text-uppercase m-2">add count</button>
    `;
    main.innerHTML = html

  }else if(e.target.classList.contains('prevBtn')) {
    counter--
    html=`
    <h1 class="text-uppercase">counter</h1>
    <h1 id="counter">${counter}</h1>
    <div class="btn-container d-flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
    <button class="btn counterBtn prevBtn text-uppercase m-2">lower count</button>
    <button class="btn counterBtn nextBtn text-uppercase m-2">add count</button>
    `;
    main.innerHTML = html
  }
  
  const button1 = document.querySelector('.prevBtn');
  const button2 = document.querySelector('.nextBtn');
  const count = document.getElementById('counter')

  if(counter > 0){
    count.style.color = 'green'
  } else if(counter < 0) {
    count.style.color = 'red'
  }
});
```

```css
.main-container {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container nextBtn">Click On Me</div>
```

Comment: thanks for help  its working now :)

Comment: Where is my upvote and green tick? :)))

Comment: sorry cant do it i need to have some kind of 15 points :))